# populate an array with 2 dimensions on the client side and get that array on server-side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm new to develop. Net. and I have a small question.
Can I populate an array with 2 dimensions on the client side (javascript) and pass that array to the server side?

If yes, How?

Comment: Would you be able to handle some kind of string manipulation on the server. And also do you want the arrays to be visible to test and see what they contain ex: select controls or just simply hidden

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON for your data. JavaScript works extremely well with JSON, and PHP can handle JSON objects.

Read more about it:

- http://json.org/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON